# relation between $E[e^{-\mu X}]$ and $\frac{\lambda}{\mu} $ where $E[X] = \frac{1}{\lambda}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X$ is a general distribution, and I am interested in the relation between $E[e^{-\mu X}]$ and $\frac{\lambda}{\mu} $, where $E[X] = \frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Answer (score 1):

In general $Ee^{-\mu x}$ may not be finite. If $X$ and $\mu$ are non-negative we can say that $Ee^{-\mu x} \geq -\frac {\mu} {\lambda}=-\frac 1 {(\frac {\lambda} {\mu})}$. [This follows by Jensen's inequality]. Nothing more can be said in general.